# Pluralize in Rails View Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pluralize, plural

I have a question about the pluralize function. In my view, I have the following line of code. It passes in an item with a certain number of votes to determine if it the word "Vote" should be pluralized.

```
 <%= pluralize(item.votes, 'Vote') %>
```

My issue is that my view passes out the word "Votes" followed by the certain number of votes (item.votes). I only want it to pass out the word "Votes". Ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
pluralize(items.votes, 'Vote').split(" ", 2)[1]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 11):

You can do simpler:

```
"Vote".pluralize(item.votes)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own method in a helper

```
def pluralize_without_count(string, count)
    count == 1 ? string : string.pluralize
end
```

and use it in your view:

```
<%= pluralize_without_count('Vote', item.votes) %>
```

Comment: if you want to consider the case of having *0* votes, you might want to slightly change this helper to: `count == 1 ? string : string.pluralize`

Comment: Yes, this should be changed to be: count == 1 ? string : string.pluralize